# Call function inside other function odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I want call function 2 inside function 1.

Function 2 need parameter (num2 and num3), after call in source I don't get any error but nothing happened aslo.

```
def function_1(self, cr, uid, ids, num1, num2, num3, context=None):
        res = {}
        if num1:
            res['sum'] = num1 + num2
            return {'value': res}
        self.function_2(cr, uid, ids, num2, num3, context)


    def function_2(self, cr, uid, ids, num2,num3, context=None):
        res = {}
        if num2:
            res['sum2'] = num2 + num3
            return {'value': res}
```

What is problem here or any other solution?

Comment: You don't need to use `self.`. It's only a change of scope, not an object.

Comment: What did you expect to happen?  I imagine function_1 returned `None`.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh  I expect number in text field....

Comment: You want it to `print` a number?  Because that's not what this code does.  First, if you want the result of `function_2` to make it out of `function_1` you have to return it.  The value it looks like your returning is a mapping of `'value'` to some mapping of either `'sum'` or `'sum2'` to an integer.  Or sometimes `None`.  Keep in mind that any time a function reaches its end without returning something it returns the `None` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `self` in `function_2` and you also need the `return` keyword, because after `function_2` evaluates and returns it's value to the caller which is `function_1`, `function_1` also has to return that result to it's caller. if you don't add a return statement `function_1` would end up returning `None` to it's caller.

```
def function_1(self, cr, uid, ids, num1, num2, num3, context=None):
    # i'll place the function definition at the top (personal preference)
    def function_2(cr, uid, ids, num2,num3, context=None):
        res = {}
        if num2:
            res['sum2'] = num2 + num3
            return {'value': res}

    res = {}
    if num1:
        res['sum'] = num1 + num2
        return {'value': res}

    return function_2(cr, uid, ids, num2, num3, context=context)
```

Personally i don't see the need to have a nested function. i would have written it like this.

```
def function_1(self, cr, uid, ids, num1, num2, num3, context=None):
    res = {}
    if num1:
        res['sum'] = num1 + num2
        return {'value': res}

    elif num2:
        res['sum2'] = num2 + num3
        return {'value': res}

    else:
        pass # return some default value here
```